# obiee display measures even if it is null

Tags: obiee

I am making an analysis with obiee 11g.
I have a program code and some measures I make in my analyse. For example:
count of objectives, count of courses,...
I make this by a formula `COUNT(DISTINCT objectives)` for example.

The problem is that I have no row, when one of those counts are null. 
For example I have a program course with 2 objectives and 2 courses, then it will display

```
Program count of objectives count of courses
1           2               2
```

But I have a program 2 with 3 objectives and no courses. The row will not be display, but I want the following result:

```
Program count of objectives count of courses
1           2                   2
2           3                   0
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Analysis properties -> Data -> Include Null Values